# Bridge 2 wifi connections

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi, bridge

I have set up Ubuntu desktop on my laptop with an internal wifi card and an external USB WiFi dongle.

Both WiFi interfaces work.

I'd like to make one into an access point, and the other into the Internet connection to the outside world.

Is there a way to do this?
Ultimately I'm hoping to use nginx or something else to modify the traffic passing between both interfaces in a MITM style, for my own learning and entertainment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if one of your wireless cards supports AP Mode, you can use it as an Access Point.

Here's an explanation on how to do that using hostapd and dnsmasq: https://seravo.fi/2014/create-wireless-access-point-hostapd .

I've recently finished a project that does this automatically on Ubuntu 14.04. It's composed of a shell script that handles all the operations, and a Python GUI that is used to turn on/off and configure the AP. As soon as I can I'll upload it on GitHub.